# Docker remote error (tls: unrecognized name) in GitHub actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-registry

I am trying to setup GitHub actions for automated docker image build and push. Building works fine but while trying to log in to the private repository, I get `Error response from daemon: Get "https://***/v2/": remote error: tls: unrecognized name`

I have gotten this locally and have been able to fix it by restarting docker daemon. That isn't possible on the runner however.

Relevant line of the action:

```yaml
      - run: echo "$REG_PASS" | docker login -u "$REG_USER" --password-stdin "$REG_URL"
```

Is there a fix for this in the Actions context? Also, could this issue be rooted in the docker registry server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to your registry server's SSL/TLS configuration or a DNS issue and does not seem to be specifically a GitHub Actions problem. It is more related to the Docker registry or the network of your environment.

I will advise you try the following options.

- Make sure that the SSL/TLS certificates for your Docker registry are valid and correctly installed. A misconfiguration could lead to the error you're seeing.
- Ensure DNS settings are valid: try and access the URL to be sure they are resolved correctly
- since you mentioned it is a private registry, check your registry logs, it might also provide valuable insights into the issue.

Also, are you using the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name)  for your Docker registry in the GitHub Actions workflow? That might also be a cause of the issue.

Comment: I am using the FQDN. Are you saying it causes problems or not usng it causes them? Also the URL is resolved but only `/v2` endpoint seems to indicate a secure connection (with browser). Registry domain as is opens a blank, non-secure site. Would this indicate a SSL issue?

Comment: I mean the FQDN is what is the right approach, so you did the right thing, 
 also the fact that the /v2 shows secure connection  while the other path  shows insecure indicate a general SSL configuration problem.  is it possible that SSL is correctly configured for /v2 endpoint but not for the root domain ? 

additionally on browser what happens when you try 'https://fqdn/v2/_catalog'  ?

Comment: I added the HTTPS protocol to the URL and it resulted in the same UNREGOCNIZED_NAME alert. Seems to be indeed a problem with SSL. I will mark this as accepted answer and debug this further myself. Thank you!